# In JavaScript testing the equality of two values where the content includes &

Tags: javascript

The following code snippet demonstrates my problem.  When I test a string that contains the "&" the result is always false.

How should this be handled?  JavaScript solution only please.

```js
  var PROJECT = "This & Somthing Else";
  var PROJECT2 = "This and Somthing Else";

  function testValues()
  {
   if (PROJECT == document.getElementById("curPrjct").innerHTML)
   {
    alert("The Same");
   }else{
    alert("Not The Same");
   }
  }

  function testValues2()
  {
   if (PROJECT2 == document.getElementById("curPrjct2").innerHTML)
   {
    alert("The Same");
   }else{
    alert("Not The Same");
   }
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
</head>
 <body>
 <span id="curPrjct">This & Somthing Else</span> <br>
 <input type="button" value="Go This will fail" onclick="testValues()"><br><br>
 <span id="curPrjct2">This and Somthing Else</span> <br>
 <input type="button" value="Go This will work" onclick="testValues2()">
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: because `&amp;` != `&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with trying to look at the HTML is that when it is converted to a DOM and then back to HTML, *it will be normalised*.

`&` will be converted to `&amp;`.

Compare the `textContent` instead of the HTML.

```js
  var PROJECT = "This & Somthing Else";
  var PROJECT2 = "This and Somthing Else";

  function testValues()
  {
   if (PROJECT == document.getElementById("curPrjct").textContent)
   {
    alert("The Same");
   }else{
    alert("Not The Same");
   }
  }

  function testValues2()
  {
   if (PROJECT2 == document.getElementById("curPrjct2").textContent)
   {
    alert("The Same");
   }else{
    alert("Not The Same");
   }
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
</head>
 <body>
 <span id="curPrjct">This & Somthing Else</span> <br>
 <input type="button" value="Now this will work" onclick="testValues()"><br><br>
 <span id="curPrjct2">This and Somthing Else</span> <br>
 <input type="button" value="Go This will work" onclick="testValues2()">
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Will mark answer when my 10 minutes are up